# My Facebook App Canvas URL is not secure url

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an App on Facebook.
My website is a secure site, and opens with https.
But the generated Canvas URL is not a secure URL. 
Below is the generated URL
http://apps.facebook.com/mcadeveloper

Problem:
This url is not responding when the user is not logged-in in Facebook.

Is there any way to change the Canvas URL to secure URL?

Comment: You have to provide 2 URLs to your canvass,  a secure version and a non secure version of the same.  Please visit your app settings.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question.
I need to change the Canvas Page URL i.e. "http://apps.facebook.com/xyz" to secure Canvas Page URL like "https://apps.facebook.com/xyz"

Comment: You could be accessing your page/canvas with a Facebook account that is set to use http instead of https.  Please check the Facebook account settings you are using and change the settings (if need be).

Comment: Yess, we are doing that, but it means that if anyone want to use this app, he has to enable the secure browsing first.
Can't we have some other option to make it Secure Canvas Page URL?